# residuals in rugarch same length as original series despite lag

Tags: r

I am using the `rugarch` package in `R` to fit a GARCH-model with ARMA-order (1,0) in the mean equation. Despite the lag, the residual series are somehow the same length as the original series.

```
library(rugarch)
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(1000)
spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1,1)), mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1,0)))
fit <- ugarchfit(spec, x)
coef <- fit@fit$coef

xhat <- fit@fit$fitted.values
myxhat <- coef["mu"] + coef["ar1"]*c(NA, x[-length(x)])
resid <- fit@fit$residuals
myresid <- x-myxhat

length(resid)==length(x)
[1] TRUE

head(cbind(x, xhat, myxhat, resid, myresid))
               x        xhat      myxhat       resid     myresid
[1,] -0.56047565  0.01615305          NA -0.57662870          NA
[2,] -0.23017749  0.03207118  0.03162527 -0.26224867 -0.26180276
[3,]  1.55870831  0.02295313  0.02250722  1.53575518  1.53620110
[4,]  0.07050839 -0.02642998 -0.02687590  0.09693838  0.09738429
[5,]  0.12928774  0.01465254  0.01420663  0.11463519  0.11508111
[6,]  1.71506499  0.01302991  0.01258399  1.70203508  1.70248099

tail(cbind(x, xhat, myxhat, resid, myresid))
                 x         xhat       myxhat       resid    myresid
[995,]   0.3132288  0.022487416  0.022041503  0.29074136  0.2911873
[996,]  -0.0899752  0.007952121  0.007506207 -0.09792732 -0.0974814
[997,]   1.0705160  0.019082774  0.018636861  1.05143326  1.0518792
[998,]  -1.3511004 -0.012953185 -0.013399098 -1.33814720 -1.3377013
[999,]  -0.5226167  0.053896785  0.053450872 -0.57651348 -0.5760676
[1000,] -0.2491907  0.031026066  0.030580152 -0.28021674 -0.2797708
```

Does anyone know how (or why?) `rugarch` computes the residual for the first observation? I see that someone has tried to ask this question before [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148800/how-are-residuals-calculated-in-rugarch-package) without answer. Thankful for any help.

Comment: How about comparing `head` and `tail` of your `x`, your fitted values of `x` and your residuals? You can try to construct the residuals yourself based on the parameter estimates of the garch model and see whether the first or last observation is the offending one, as a start.

Comment: My own calculations are similar, but not exactly the same (which can perhaps be written off to some rounding of the coefficients when the results are presented). I noticed however that the first fitted value is equal to the intercept in the mean equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rugarch` uses the intercept as the fitted value for those observations which are usually removed when estimating an equation with lagged values.

```
coef["mu"]
mu 
0.01615305
```